# Не работают статические файлы в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я посмотрел документацию django по подключению статических файлов и они частично работают вот пример

### Это у меня в css написано:

```
a.navbar-logo{
  font-family: 'RUSNeverwinter';
  src: url('шрифты/RUSNeverwinter.ttf');
  font-size: 28pt;
}

a.nav_two{
  font-family: 'RUSNeverwinter';
    src: url('шрифты/RUSNeverwinter.ttf');
  font-size: 22pt;
}
```

### Выводит оно следующие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### сам код html:

```
              <a class="navbar-logo" href="#">I</a>
              <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav_two" href="/{{languages.id}}">{{languages.language}} описание</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav_two" href="/{{languages.id}}/librarys">Библиотеки</a>
            </li>
```

### setting:

```
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
...
        STATIC_URL = '/static/'
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

        MEDIA_URL = '/photologue/'
        MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'photologue')

        STATICFILES_DIRS =(

            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_dev'),    
        )
```

### шаблон base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"> 
  <body>
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

### urls:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### Версия джанго 2.2

### Версия питона 3.8

Answer (score 0):

2 Ошибки.

1)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
   <!DOCTYPE html>
```

2)

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' 
 <body>
```

правильный код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'css/styles.css'%}> 
  <body>
          {% block content %}{% endblock %} <!-- может быть и тут ошибка -->
  </body>
</html>
```

***НЕ исключаю, что и в других файлах ошибка. Потому что не по конвенциям написан. Но ошибки, указанные ниже, точно надо исправить***

Comment: не помогло 2 ошибка это мой мисклмк при на писаний вопроса а насчёт {% block content %}{% endblock %} то все шаблоны работают

Comment: ну вообще то статические файлы вот так подключаются  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">